# How to link to tabs with jtabs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I added tabs to a section of my page I am working on (stridertechnologies.com/stoutwebsite/products.php)using the steps found at this website: http://code-tricks.com/create-a-simple-html5-tabs-using-jquery/

I want to link to the different tabs from the home page, but I am not sure how to do that outside of anchor names with html and that doesn't work with this, and there aren't any instructions on how to do it on the site.

It seems like there should be something really simple I can add to my javascript to detect which link they clicked on and make it the active tab.

javascript:

```
;(function($){
  $.fn.html5jTabs = function(options){
    return this.each(function(index, value){
      var obj = $(this),
      objFirst = obj.eq(index),
      objNotFirst = obj.not(objFirst);

      $("#" +  objNotFirst.attr("data-toggle")).hide();
      $(this).eq(index).addClass("active");

      obj.click(function(evt){

        toggler = "#" + obj.attr("data-toggle");
        togglerRest = $(toggler).parent().find("div");

        togglerRest.hide().removeClass("active");
        $(toggler).show().addClass("active");

        //toggle Active Class on tab buttons
        $(this).parent("div").find("a").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        return false; //Stop event Bubbling and PreventDefault
      });
    });
  };
}(jQuery));
```

Comment: terminology issue: it's "javascript" (or js, abbreviated); not jscript (which is a microsoft thing) or java script (which doesn't exist). That might sound like nit picking, but calling things by their name is a fairly important thing when it comes to technologies. That said, stackoverflow is here for you once you found a way to do something, started doing it, and then get stuck. It's not really the place to go before you start, so: google for some JS tutorials, try them, and once you get stuck on specific code problems, SO will be here for you.

Comment: If you could show us some code to what you have tried so far, that would beso much better for someone here to help you.

Comment: AYE! What is this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20811090/linking-to-jquery-tabs-from-another-page ?  Duplication ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from a duplicated question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/20811416/3123649.

You could pass the tab div id in the url from the link and use that to select.

Home page links from index.html:

```
<a href="products.php?tabId=tile">tile</a>
<a href="products.php?tabId=metal">metal</a>
```

Add this javascript to the tab page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// To get parameter from url
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
    results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

    $.extend($.expr[':'], {
    attrNameStart: function (el, i, props) {
        var hasAttribute = false;
        $.each(el.attributes, function (i, attr) {
            if (attr.name.indexOf(props[3]) !== -1) {
                hasAttribute = true;
                return false;
            }
        });


        return hasAttribute;
    }
});

// deselect tabs and select the tab by id
function focusTab(id) {
    $("#tile").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#metal").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#shingle").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#flat").hide().removeClass("active");
    $("#custom").hide().removeClass("active");
    var toggle = $(id).parent().find("div");
    toggle.hide().removeClass("active");
    $('a:attrNameStart(data-toggle)').removeClass("active");
    var id1 = getParameterByName("tabId");
    var toggler = $('*[data-toggle=' + id1 + ']');        
    $(toggler).addClass("active");        
    $(id).show().addClass("active");
}

 $(function() {
    $(".tabs a").html5jTabs();

    // Get the tab id from the url
    var tabId = "#" + getParameterByName("tabId");
    // Focus the tab       
    focusTab(tabId);
});
</script>
```

EDIT: Replace the original `focusTab` function with the edit.  Also add the extend function `attrNameStart`.  This should deselect the default active tab.
EDIT2: `focusTab` had a bug, it should work now

** I looked at your site and my solutions seems to be working for you.  One thing I noticed.  You initialize the `html5jTabs()` twice.

Remove the first call at the top

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".tabs a").html5jTabs();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? Basically we are taking the value of data-toggle in our  buttons, and passing it into the selector for each tab content

JS

```
$('a[data-toggle]').on('click', function () {
    var dataToggle = $(this).data('toggle');

    $('.tabContent > div').removeClass('active');
    $('.tabContent > div#'+dataToggle+'').addClass('active');
});
```

working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/whiteb0x/VdeqY/

Comment: I have the tabs working, but I can't link to a specific tab from another page.